# Unable to promote a site on the Sites page

Tags: team-sites

I am the Global Admin for our SharePoint tenant. However, I am not able to promote a site on the Sites page. I have read [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Promote-sites-on-the-Sites-page-BE0C9245-F465-4C3B-96FF-8046BD551BF3), though lack the "Manage the promoted sites below" link that it displays.

Here is a screen shot of what the Global Admin **actually** sees on our Sites page. Note that there is not a "Manage the promoted sites below" link.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of what the documentation says the Global Admin **should** see.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [this blog post](http://blog.ciaops.com/2014/04/managing-promoted-sites-in-office-365.html), we found another way to promote a site.

1. portal.office.com/admin > ADMIN > SharePoint
2. user profiles
3. Manage promoted sites

[image]